# How to EASILY detect Right/Left swipe gestures for modifying current views - android?

Tags: android, view, swipe, gesture

(Please read before flagging as a duplicate, it's not.)

After nearly 3 hours of battling with the deprecated answers on SO, I finally decided to ask this question.

I reckon my situation is a bit different:

I'll explain with a shortened example. So, I have an activity with say 5-6 buttons. Each of them when clicked starts another activity and each of them sends a different Resource ID for a different XML string resource (as an intent)

In the second activity I have a textview in which I show the string resource which has been passed to it as an intent. So you press 1st button, you get to see one string, the 2nd button another string and so on.

I want, in the second activity, say the user presses first button. The first string is shown.

He swipes "Right to left", and the second string pops up... To go back,a "Left to right" swipe... and to move forward a "right to left" swipe again.

I can handle the transition animations for it to look decent, but I don't know exactly what to do.

Here's what I'm thinking.

I need to make an array of Resource ID's, Detect the swipe direction ...and increment/ decrement the index of the array and update the activity with the new string.

The only problem I have with the above solution is actually detecting the swipe.

So, how to do this ?

(I have tried literally every single question on SO, 90% are deprecated, 9% require viewpager which I couldn't understand, and the remaining 1% might have had the answer but I couldn't find one which did.)

Comment: Thank you for commenting, had I thought that I would have gotten an answer for a 5000 word article that in the end got me where I started, I would have written it. Just because you probably know more than me, doesn't make you right. If you can help, I'd appreciate it. If not, the least anyone should do is not discourage.

Comment: Also, there aren't 400,000 thousand questions on Gesture detection... It's around 20-25. Stating huge figures doesn't help in making a point if they're wrong.

Comment: "there aren't 400,000 thousand questions on Gesture detection" -- you are the one that wrote "I have tried literally every single question on SO". It is in your final paragraph, the one in parentheses.

Comment: Wow. If it weren't for 300k rep, I'd think you are like 12 yrs old or something. Thank you for sabotaging this question.

Comment: "I'd think you are like 12 yrs old or something" -- pot, meet kettle. As I wrote in my first comment, you should consider explaining what techniques you examined that you think are deprecated. `ViewPager` *is* the way to "EASILY detect Right/Left swipe gestures", but you indicated that you could not understand how to use it. There are plenty of other lower-level techniques listed [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html), but we have no way of knowing what of those you tried.

Comment: I ain't dropping to your level. Thank you for the wonderful conversation.